Akshata use in Vishnu worship
In the footnote of Bhagavatam 11.3, it says

As Bhāvāratha Dīpikā notes the akṣatas are to be used for application on the forehead of Hari and not elsewhere in the worship. He quotes an authority which prohibits the use of akṣatas in Viṣṇu-worship.

This question is related to the highlighted texts here.
a/ Why akshata is prohibited in Vishnu puja?
b/ Why only on forehead?
c/ Where these prohibitions are stated?

Here is a partial answer:

Never worship Visnu with rice; Ganes’a with Tulasî leaves; the Devî Durgâ with Durba grass and S’iva with Ketakî flower. The
under-mentioned flowers are pleasing to the Devî :-- Mallikâ, Jâti,
Kutaja, Panasa, Palâsa, Vakula, Lodha, Karavîra, S’ins’apa, Aparâjitâ,
Bandhûka, Vaka, Madanta, Sindhuvâra, Palâs’a, Durbhâ, S’allakî,
Mâdhavî, Arka, Mandâra, Ketakî, Karnikâra, Kadamba, Lotus, Champaka,
Yûthikâ, Tagara, etc
Devi Bhagavatam Book 11; Chapter 17

So the Devi Bhagavata Purana is one of the scriptures that prohibit the use of Akshata in Vishnu worship.

Thank you. I checked with someone learned here and he said it's not that akshata is not at all allowed...during gandha, akshata, etc seva we can offer but not to be offered during nama archana. The message here is, it's not preferred. He quoted ganesha puja as well where during patra-puja tulasi is offered.

Ok .. that's nice info @Kanthri

In the Vaikhanasa and Sri Vaishnava sampradayas, Akshatas are used for worshipping Vishnu. No such prohibition exists.
This can be seen, for example, in this video starting from around 8:20. The complete idol of the Deity is worshipped with akshata here.

Thanks. But this is not the answer.
